# How to replace all occurrences of a multiline string in a file with another multiline string in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file products.txt with below content -

```
ID      Name
w01     Whipped cream
c01     Cocoa Powder
    s01     Jaggery
        e01     Egg
f05     Flour
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
    s01     Jaggery
        e01     Egg
f05     Flour
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    s01     Jaggery
        e01     Egg
f05     Flour
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I need to replace the below text -

```
    s01     Jaggery
        e01     Egg
```

with -

```
            something
    else
```

Please note the tabs at the beginning and middle of the lines.

Appreciate your help in finding a solution for above using awk or sed.

Thank you!

Comment: Should the data remain indented with tabs in the way that you show? It seems odd as the header seems to indicate two fields per row.

Comment: Rather that trying to replace one muliline string with another, couldn't this be formulated as replacing records with certain values for ID with new data?

Comment: It is not possible to see the tabs in your post, there is just a mixture of 4, 5 and 8 spaces. Please edit your post to have one tab correspond exactly to 8 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed, you can use the `N` command to join lines and then operate on multiple lines (e.g. using s to search replace). In your expression, use `\t` for tabs and `\n` for line feeds (which will be there only after merging lines with `N`.

Example:

```
sed -e'/^\ts01\tJaggery/N;s/\ts01\tJaggery\n\t\te01\tEgg/\t\tsomething\n\telse/'
```

The above assumes one tab before s01, one between s01 and Jaggery, two before e01 and again one between e01 and Egg. The command tells sed to act upon lines matching regexp `^\ts01\tJaggery` only, join those lines with the next line (`N`), then perform a replace operation (`s`) that includes the tab-characters and line-feeds as `\t` and `\n`.

Comment: Thank you so much treuss! The above works like a  CHARM for me. Also, I believe I need to use backslash to escape any special characters, correct?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "special character". `sed` works, by default, with POSIX regular expressions, so any character that has a special meaning as POSIX re (e.g. `.`, `*`, `^`, `$`, brackets) have to be escaped with a backslash to match the actual character.

Comment: How about spaces? Escaping with a backslash works for a single space but is not working for multiple spaces though. Thank you!

Comment: I could escape more than one space also with one backslash character.

Comment: how do I get the same above working if it is a larger file? It doesn't seem to work with a file that has 520lines of text. Appreciate your answer for this also. Thank you!

Comment: Spaces do not need to be escaped. sed works with files of  millions of lines, so I doubt it has trouble with 520. I recommend, that if you still have questions, post a new question, rather than using the comment section of the answer.

Comment: For some reason the same above command doesn't work with large file on my RHEL8 system though. I tried copying a 100 lines to another file and the command works like  CHARM with that also. I posted a new question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724884/is-there-any-limitation-on-file-size-when-sed-is-used-to-search-and-replace-a-mu. thank you!